# Symbolize using schemas, quantifiers and logical connective.

Tags: propositional-calculus, quantifiers

How can I symbolize the follow sentence:

"not all integers numbers are positive"

I tried to do this:

if x∈ℤ  and P(x)= x>0

(∃x)¬p(x)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "not all" is $\lnot \forall$ that is equiv to $\exists \lnot$. Thus, that part is good.

Comment: Maybe you have to express in symbolic form also the part "$x$ is an integer". This, you can use a "more math" styled formlua : $\exists x (x \in \mathbb Z \land (x \le 0))$ instead of a pure one : $\exists x (\mathbb Z (x) \land \lnot \text {Pos}(x))$.

Comment: I'll consider your advice, thanks.